# adding text to the middle of a line

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, sh

I am in need of assistance adding text to a few places in a line of text using sed or awk.  This is the output of the df command that I have written to test.txt

```
fsu:/dev/sda3             34407336   3348680  29282672  11% /
fsu:/dev/sda1               124427     11578    106425  10% /boot
fsu:tmpfs                  4086720         0   4086720   0% /dev/shm
fsu:/dev/sdb1             20635732    725376  18862116   4% /cmdb
fsu:/dev/sdc              51606140   2531372  46453328   6% /data
```

I would like to make test.txt look like this:

```
fsu:/dev/sda3 T: 34407336 U: 3348680  A: 29282672  P: 11% M: /
fsu:/dev/sda1 T: 124427 U: 11578 A: 106425 P: 10% M: /boot
fsu:tmpfs T: 4086720 U: 0 A: 4086720 P: 0% M: /dev/shm
fsu:/dev/sdb1 T: 20635732 U: 725376 A: 18862116 P: 4% M: /cmdb
fsu:/dev/sdc T: 51606140 U: 2531372 A:46453328 P: 6% M: /data
```

I can not figure out how to add the letters and colons in front of the numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1, "T:", $2, "U:", $3, "A:", $4, "P:", $5, "M:", $6}' file
```

Output:

```
fsu:/dev/sda3 T: 34407336 U: 3348680 A: 29282672 P: 11% M: /
fsu:/dev/sda1 T: 124427 U: 11578 A: 106425 P: 10% M: /boot
fsu:tmpfs T: 4086720 U: 0 A: 4086720 P: 0% M: /dev/shm
fsu:/dev/sdb1 T: 20635732 U: 725376 A: 18862116 P: 4% M: /cmdb
fsu:/dev/sdc T: 51606140 U: 2531372 A: 46453328 P: 6% M: /data
```

Pipe through `column -t` if you want the columns aligned nicely.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf "%s T: %s U: %s A: %s P: %s M: %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 }' file
```

Results:

```
fsu:/dev/sda3 T: 34407336 U: 3348680 A: 29282672 P: 11% M: /
fsu:/dev/sda1 T: 124427 U: 11578 A: 106425 P: 10% M: /boot
fsu:tmpfs T: 4086720 U: 0 A: 4086720 P: 0% M: /dev/shm
fsu:/dev/sdb1 T: 20635732 U: 725376 A: 18862116 P: 4% M: /cmdb
fsu:/dev/sdc T: 51606140 U: 2531372 A: 46453328 P: 6% M: /data
```